# Dry hopping in secondary...

Tags: dry-hop

What is the time frame for dry-hopping in secondary?  How soon can I bottle, and how long before tannins/off flavors leech out of the hops?

Answer (score 5):

There is a wealth of information from three guys who know hops on the [dry-hopping episode](http://thebrewingnetwork.com/shows/Brew-Strong/Brew-Strong-12-08-08-Dry-Hopping) of Brew Strong.  Jamil, John Palmer, and Mike "Tasty" McDole (who won the Sam Adam's Longshot Competition with an awesome IPA) cover all aspects of dry hopping your beer to get the best results.

They reveal that you only need a few days of dry hopping to get great hop aroma and how long before before grassy or vegetal off-flavors begin to come out of the hops.

Answer (score 1):

I try and give my dry hop 1 week 2 at the most. Hop aroma quickly diminishes so I try and get the beer out and kegged or bottles after a week. When "life" happens and you find yourself dry hopping for 3 or 4 weeks I notice less aroma but never off flavors. It must take an extended period before any negative effects begin.